# intellij git gutter on the left of editor lost

Tags: git, intellij-idea

hello I'm using IntelliJ idea and I fell in the problem I always use a future to check the difference between master code and my branch but today for some reason (i thing a plugin did that) removed it and I can't seem to find anyone on the internet with a solution

[image]

on the left side, there was a blue sign that I have changed something now its gone any help

[image]

^^ that blue-green lines have disappeared

Comment: Do you still have any Git options in the top drop down menus?  When you configure your project's version control, is Git still selected as the provider?

Comment: yes the only thing that changed is that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go to `File | Settings | Editor | General` and tick `Highlight modified lines in gutter` option.

Comment: Just wanted to add this note. I was banging my head against the wall, as this seemed not to work at all for me with the setting enabled. It appears that IntelliJ has a bug that a file that is a *symbolic link*, this feature does not work. Ensure that you open the actual file the link points to.

Comment: A more up-to-date answer: `Preferences -> Version Control -> Confirmation | Gutter`
credit goes to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70292278/6535270

Comment: @orpheus could you add this as an answer rather than a comment? I want to upvote as a full answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had to run the following on the project directory:

```
git config --global --add safe.directory <directory>
```

I'm using Windows and do modify that project in WSL2