# Intellij doesn't show gutter highlights for code line changes?

Tags: intellij-idea

In Intellij Idea by default when a line of code changes, in left gutter it shows color to reflect that change. The problem is by changing lines the gutter doesn't change at all. I am using SVN as a version controller, and can do update and commit.

Comment: try `Invalidate Caches/Restart` option from the File option and see if you are able to view the color changes in the left gutter.

Comment: Caches are not related to Version Control Changes highlighting. Invalidating caches will not help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have the **Highlight modified lines in gutter** option enabled in Settings | Editor | General -> Other.

Answer (score 7):

Just an update. In IntelliJ IDEA 2021.3, this option is in `Preferences -> Version Control -> Confirmation | Gutter`. See image below:

[image: IntelliJ IDEA Preferences]

Comment: Finally I found an up to date answer. Thank you a lot!

Comment: Thanks, finally something helpful. No idea why IntelliJ decided to disable a setting i had in previous versions though…